# how to use ueye_cam to drive my UI1221-m camera

Tags: ros, ueye-cam, ueye

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all
i have an ueye UI-1221-M camera and i am trying to use ueye_cam to drive it.
i have installed the IDS driver and can use the driver to open the camera.
when i use "roslaunch ueye_cam rgb8.launch" the erro comes as follow.

```
    process[nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [2384]
    process[ueye_cam_nodelet-2]: started with pid [2385]
    [ INFO] [1383891971.818538867]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
    [ERROR] [1383891971.834649094]: Failed to load nodelet [/ueye_cam_nodelet] of type [ueye_cam/include/ueye_cam_nodelet]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class ueye_cam/include/ueye_cam_nodelet with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  asctec_autopilot/AutoPilotNodelet asctec_proc/AsctecProcNodelet depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus pcl/BAGReader pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VoxelGrid stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2 ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet
    [FATAL] [1383891971.834927628]: Service call failed!
    [ueye_cam_nodelet-2] process has died [pid 2385, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load ueye_cam/include/ueye_cam_nodelet nodelet_manager __name:=ueye_cam_nodelet __log:=/home/uav/.ros/log/91855d0c-483e-11e3-9892-9c4e3647a14c/ueye_cam_nodelet-2.log].
    log file: /home/uav/.ros/log/91855d0c-483e-11e3-9892-9c4e3647a14c/ueye_cam_nodelet-2*.log
```

** It seems that missing lib file how to deal with the problem? any help is appriciate**

[Update]
Hi, thanks for your reply
I have re-cloned the code and  the error didn't disappear:

```
    [ INFO] [1383981887.637572692]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
    [ERROR] [1383981887.726106300]: Failed to load nodelet [/ueye_cam_nodelet] of type [ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet]: Could not find library corresponding to plugin ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
    [FATAL] [1383981887.726402185]: Service call failed!
    [ueye_cam_nodelet-2] process has died [pid 6465, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet nodelet_manager __name:=ueye_cam_nodelet __log:=/home/uav/.ros/log/fda46e70-490f-11e3-bba7-9c4e3647a14c/ueye_cam_nodelet-2.log].
    log file: /home/uav/.ros/log/fda46e70-490f-11e3-bba7-9c4e3647a14c/ueye_cam_nodelet-2*.log
```

And i find problems when i build the package"rosmake ueye_cam"   The MAKE process is really fast , i think many of the file did not MAKE correctly...

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ueye_cam']                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/uav/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131109-153613
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ueye_cam'] to:
['ueye_cam']                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
 No Makefile in package rosclean
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
 No Makefile in package rosparam
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
 No Makefile in package rosmaster
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> console_bridge [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< console_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package console_bridge
 No Makefile in package console_bridge
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> class_loader [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
 No Makefile in package opencv2
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< class_loader ROS_NOBUILD in package class_loader
 No Makefile in package class_loader
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
 No Makefile in package smclib
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers
 No Makefile in package camera_calibration_parsers
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
 No Makefile in package pluginlib
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
 No Makefile in package bond
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
 No Makefile in package bondcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
 No Makefile in package nodelet
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
 No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
 No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
 No Makefile in package topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport
 No Makefile in package image_transport
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
 No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> camera_info_manager [ make ]                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
 No Makefile in package rosmsg
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_info_manager
 No Makefile in package camera_info_manager
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
 No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
 No Makefile in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> ueye_cam [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< ueye_cam ROS_NOBUILD in package ueye_cam
 No Makefile in package ueye_cam
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 48 packages with 0 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/uav/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131109-153613
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98861/how-to-use-ueye_cam-to-drive-my-ui1221-m-camera/) by [vippt](https://answers.ros.org/users/8031/vippt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vippt](https://answers.ros.org/users/8031/vippt/) on 2013-11-07**:
@anqixu  please help me with it

**Comment by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) on 2013-11-09**:
Your new run shows the correct nodelet type of ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet rather than ueye_cam/include/ueye_cam_nodelet. Also, the default repo branch is for catkin, not rosmake. So either use catkin_make (groovy&up) or switch branch: git clone https://github.com/anqixu/ueye_cam.git --branch fuerte

**Comment by [vippt](https://answers.ros.org/users/8031/vippt/) on 2013-11-10**:
hi anqixu thanks
i am useing the groovy but i can't config the catkin_make (i'm new here), so i downloaded the fuerte code and it works with my ueye.

**Comment by [Vero](https://answers.ros.org/users/10711/vero/) on 2014-01-10**:
Hi anqixu. I'm using ROS hydro, compiling the package with catkin_make, but I still have the same problem:

### [ERROR] [1389397299.178431342]: Failed to load nodelet [/ueye_cam_nodelet] of type [ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet]: Could not find library corresponding to plugin ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.

The library exist and it is in the right path.

How can I solve this problem?

**Comment by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) on 2014-01-11**:
@Vero: hmm that's very weird. try checking out the fuerte branch and compiling (with rosbuild). Please also confirm that under the path [catkin_ws]/devel/lib, you have the files libueye_cam_nodelet.so libueye_wrapper.so

**Comment by [Vero](https://answers.ros.org/users/10711/vero/) on 2014-01-11**:
The package ueye_came-fuerte compiles and runs. The hydro version still has a problem. I can confirm that  under the path [catkin_ws]/devel/lib there are the files libueye_cam_nodelet.so libueye_wrapper.so

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-01-12**:
Since the libraries exist but are not getting found we need some more information to narrow it down. Can you please add the output of the following commands from the shell where your roslaunch invocation failed to your question? "rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nodelet | grep ueye" and "env | grep CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" and "".

**Comment by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) on 2014-01-17**:
Since your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH does not contain the path of your workspace it looks like that you have not sourced the workspace/devel/setup.bash file. Can you make sure to do that and try again?

**Comment by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) on 2014-01-20**:
Please make sure to source your [catkin_workspace]/devel/setup.bash file prior to compiling and running any catkin-based ROS packages, such as ueye_cam. The erroneous behaviors resulting from not sourcing this file appears to be consistent with several of the symptoms reported here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solve the problem.  It was a problem of the id of the cameras. I used the master_slaves_rgb8.launch and I modified the id name.

---

Originally posted by [Vero](https://answers.ros.org/users/10711/vero/) with karma: 16 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that your launch file is incorrectly trying to load a nodelet of type "ueye_cam/include/ueye_cam_nodelet" and failing, since the actual nodelet is of the type "ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet" (which has been compiled successfully on your machine, if you look at the rest of the printout).

Please try updating your code from the github repo and trying again.

See: https://github.com/anqixu/ueye_cam/blob/master/launch/rgb8.launch

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2013-11-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vippt](https://answers.ros.org/users/8031/vippt/) on 2013-11-08**:
HI @anqixu ,thank you for your help
i think i haven't  install the package correctly,  it seems missing some lib? i don't know :-(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I basically have the same problem

I am using a UI 1221LE camera from a raspberry pi running minibian with ROS indigo.
The camera is confirmed to be working from a ubuntu environment but have problems starting it from the minibian.

I have installed the arm 7 drivers and started successfully the daemon.
I have tried to use the ueye_cam from apt-get, everything was ok but could not launch.
Now i have cloned the git, compiled with catkin successfully, but when trying to run
roslaunch ueye_cam rgb8.launch

i get the output

`/root/ueye/ueye_cam/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ueye_cam/check_ueye_api: error while loading shared libraries: libueye_api.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory=REQUIRED process [check_ueye_api-1] has died! process has died [pid 7478, exit code 127, cmd /root/ueye/ueye_cam/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ueye_cam/check_ueye_api __name:=check_ueye_api __log:=/root/.ros/log/2823c8ee-1392-11e7-a344-b827eba280a7/check_ueye_api-1.log]. log file: /root/.ros/log/2823c8ee-1392-11e7-a344-b827eba280a7/check_ueye_api-1*.log Initiating shutdown!`

I confirm to have sourced catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
also, i confirm that the directory /devel/lib includes the files libueye_cam_nodelet.so and libueye_wrapper.so and they are not empty.

Moreover,
Having commented the line
`node name="check_ueye_api" pkg="ueye_cam" type="check_ueye_api" required="true" /`
in src/launch/rg8.launch.
i get a different error:

`[ERROR] [1490697836.989684294]: Failed to load nodelet [/ueye_cam_nodelet] of type [ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet] even after refreshing the cache: Failed to load library /root/ueye/ueye_cam/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libueye_cam_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libueye_api.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)[ERROR] [1490697836.989874241]: The error before refreshing the cache was: Failed to load library /root/ueye/ueye_cam/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libueye_cam_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libueye_api.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) [FATAL] [1490697836.990713562]: Failed to load nodelet '/ueye_cam_nodelet of type ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet to manager nodelet_manager' [ueye_cam_nodelet-2] process has died [pid 7668, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet nodelet_manager __name:=ueye_cam_nodelet __log:=/root/.ros/log/2823c8ee-1392-11e7-a344-b827eba280a7/ueye_cam_nodelet-2.log]. log file: /root/.ros/log/2823c8ee-1392-11e7-a344-b827eba280a7/ueye_cam_nodelet-2*.log`

** having followed this thread on the ros page, I get the same problem, but unable to fix.

Moreover. i tried also to compile the fuerte branch, but with no success.

Thank you!

---

Originally posted by [rhaeg](https://answers.ros.org/users/29851/rhaeg/) with karma: 11 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhaeg](https://answers.ros.org/users/29851/rhaeg/) on 2017-03-29**:
So it turns out i was using the wrong camera driver.
I was using the driver for arm7 architecture with soft float instead of the one with hard float.
the correct driver works fine and the ros_ueye_cam works well.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-04-06**:
I +1ed for your sharing valuable info, but your posts should have been posted as a separate question (and answer) so that people with the same issue/interest can find it easily in the future.